# Download, name and save a file using Python 2.7.2

Tags: python

Is it possible to download and name a file from website using Python 2.7.2 and save it on desktop? If yes, then how to do it?

Comment: Yes, there are various web frameworks (selenium, urllib,etc) you can use to download a file. Then you can use built-in modules to name or rename the file.

Comment: short answer is yes.. but it depends on where you are downloading it from. You could use urllib to download if you know the complete url for the file

Comment: `urllib2.urlopen` the remote file to read. Open a local file to write. `write` to the local file, the contents of `remoteFile.read()`. `os.rename` the local file as desired.

Comment: My question voted as off topic. I don't agree. It seems to be too short and too general. However from the answers one can understand that this question has very specific answers (solutions).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here are 3 way to do it using [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html), [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) or [urllib](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.request.html)

```
import urllib2

with open('filename','wb') as f:
    f.write(urllib2.urlopen(URL).read())
    f.close()
print "Download Complete!"
---------------------------------------
import requests

r = requests.get(URL)
with open("filename", "wb") as code:
    code.write(r.content)
print "Download Complete!"
---------------------------------------

import urllib

urllib.urlretrieve(URL, "filename")
print "Download Complete!"
```

where `filename` is the name you want the file and `URL` is the url of the file you want to download

this will save the file in the same directory as the python file you're using to download

Comment: Thanks Christian! I used 3rd option and it works. The import requests doesn't work"ImportError: No module named requests". I have one more question related to this, how know if download is complete to move to another task?

Comment: Youre welcome and you have to download requests thats why it didnt work, and i edited the question :) now when you see Download Complete! you know its done

Comment: So I don't need to worry the program will continue only after completing the download. Am I right?

Comment: yeah nothing after the download will run until the download is finished!

Comment: But what if for some network problem or something else occurs and the download was interrupted. Is it possible to limit the max allowed execution time?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `urllib.urlretrieve`:

```
urllib.urlretrieve(url[, filename[, reporthook[, data]]])
```

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve):

> Copy a network object denoted by a URL to a local file, if necessary. If the
>   URL points to a local file, or a valid cached copy of the object
>   exists, the object is not copied.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy using the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library. Here's an example that downloads the StackOverflow logo image to the current directory:

```
import requests
with open('sprites.png', 'wb') as f:
    resp = requests.get('https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png',
                        stream=True)
    for chunk in resp.iter_content(8192):
        f.write(chunk)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Code doesn't work, I'm getting error:
ImportError: No module named requests

Comment: It's a third-party module that you have to install. Click the link for installation instructions.